# Returning custom taxonomy in slug order

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a loop to pull in custom taxonomy terms that I'd like to order by slug, but when I add in the 'orderby' command my loop is broken and returns nothing.  No doubt I'm using incorrect syntax, but I can't see where for the life of me!

```
<?php

$loop = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'      => 'camp',
        'orderby'        => 'name',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'types',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $term->slug,
            ),
        )
    )
);

if ($loop->have_posts()) :
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
$terms = get_lowest_taxonomy_terms(get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), array(
    'taxonomy' => 'destinations',
    'orderby' => 'slug',
    'order' => 'ASC'                                
)) );
?>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Added additional function:

The get_lowest_taxonomy_terms is running as follows:

```
get_lowest_taxonomy_terms( $terms ) {
    // if terms is not array or its empty don't proceed
    if ( ! is_array( $terms ) || empty( $terms ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $filter = function($terms) use (&$filter) {

        $return_terms = array();
        $term_ids = array();

        foreach ($terms as $t){
            if( $t->parent == 0 ) {
                $term_ids[] = $t->term_id;
            }
        }

        foreach ( $terms as $t ) {
            if( $t->parent == false || !in_array($t->parent,$term_ids) )  {
                //remove this term
            }
            else{
                $return_terms[] = $t;
            }
        }

        if( count($return_terms) ){
            return $filter($return_terms);
        }
        else {
            return $terms;
        }

    };

    return $filter($terms);
}
```

***Desired Output***

The loop should query the taxonomy type 'destination', where that destination has the additional taxonomy of 'type'.

Screen grab of the current output:

[image]

The results are ordered into 3 cols by CSS, but as you can see, not sorting alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_terms` doesn't take an array as second parameter.

> get_the_terms( int|object $post, string $taxonomy )
>
> Parameters:
>
> `$post` (int|object) (Required) Post ID or object.
>
> `$taxonomy` (string) (Required) Taxonomy name.

[More details of `get_the_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/)

By default, `get_the_terms` doesn't have any sorting option. But, you can use `usort` to sort the returned array.

So, your last part of the code should be:

```
$terms = get_lowest_taxonomy_terms(get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'destinations' ));
```

This is a quick example of how you can sort it using `usort`:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'destinations' );
usort($terms,"so980_sort_terms_alphabetically");
function so980_sort_terms_alphabetically($a,$b) {
    return $a['slug'] > $b['slug'];//using 'slug' as sorting order
}
```

`so980_sort_terms_alphabetically` function should be in your theme's `functions.php` file.

So finally, your last part will become:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'destinations' );
usort($terms,"so980_sort_terms_alphabetically");
$terms = get_lowest_taxonomy_terms($terms);
```

### Update

I have just tested it, and it is returning a fatal error, as I have made a mistake. Error message: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Term as array`.

`get_the_terms` returns an object. So, using `$a['slug']` was causing the error.

Here, `so980_sort_terms_alphabetically` should be implemented in following way:

```
function so980_sort_terms_alphabetically($a,$b) {
    return $a->slug > $b->slug;//using 'slug' as sorting order
}
```

**This is tested, and working.

### Update 2

Since your output codes are not available in your question, I will assume that you are printing inside the loop. Instead of doing that, we will save returned terms in another array, and sort it outside the loop, so that we can get all of the terms at once.

Here is a quick example of how you can do it:

```
if ($loop->have_posts()) :
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        $pre_terms = get_lowest_taxonomy_terms(get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'product_tag'));
        if ( $pre_terms ) {
            foreach ( $pre_terms as $pre_term ) {
                $terms[] = $pre_term;
            }
        }
    endwhile;
endif;
usort($terms,"so980_sort_terms_alphabetically");

//a quick test to see if it's working or not
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo $term->slug;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Sufi. :) So I add this to functions: 
`function so980_sort_terms_alphabetically($a,$b) {
    return $a['slug'] > $b['slug'];//using 'slug' as sorting order
}
add_action( 'so980_sort_terms_alphabetically');`

Comment: And this  to replace the final part of the loop query        `<?php $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'destinations' );
       usort($terms,"so980_sort_terms_alphabetically");
       $terms = get_lowest_taxonomy_terms($terms); ?>`

Comment: @AshLoudon see my update.
By the way, you don't need to add `add_action( 'so980_sort_terms_alphabetically');`.

Comment: I've added this to my loop (to replace $terms = get_lowest etc):

      `<?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();?>

       <?php  
        $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'destinations' );
        usort($terms,"so980_sort_terms_alphabetically");
        $terms = get_lowest_taxonomy_terms($terms); 
       ?>`

and this to functions:

`<?php function so980_sort_terms_alphabetically($a,$b) {
    return $a->slug > $b->slug;//using 'slug' as sorting order
}?>`

But still not alpha-sorting

Comment: @AshLoudon what does your `get_lowest_taxonomy_terms` function do? This is probably altering your output.

Comment: Added to the original question :)

Comment: May I know, why are you using that function? Not sure what that's doing, but it's clearly altering the output.

Comment: If you are looking for only alphabetical sorting by slug, just remove that `get_lowest_taxonomy_terms` function. I am not entirely sure what it's doing, but it's not helping for the alphabetical sorting by any way.
So, it should be: `$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'destinations' ); 
usort($terms,"so980_sort_terms_alphabetically");`

Comment: I'm coming in to the project near to its conclusion, so I'm not sure why this function was included.  However, when I remove that function from the loop I get all destinations, rather than those that have been given the taxonomy of 'types' .

Comment: What do you expect to get from `get_the_terms` by passing `destinations` taxonomy? What do you actually want to do? It's becoming tough to keep up with you.

Comment: Updated the original question with the desired outcome.  Apologies for not making that clear from the beginning.

Comment: So, you have two taxonomies (destinations, types) for the `camp` post type? And want to show posts, which has both destinations and types? Can you show an example output?

Comment: That's correct.  I'll add a screen grab of the output to the question :)

Comment: Current code should already do that. It will show `destinations` for those posts, which matches `$term->slug` of `types` taxonomy, unless entire loop is under another loop, which is generating `$term->slug`.

Comment: Yes the code works properly, but just isn't sorting the results.

Comment: @AshLoudon check my update 2. I have left `get_lowest_taxonomy_terms` as it was, since it's returning your expected output.